# Windows 10 stuck at booting after fresh reinstall on GPT, not on MBR

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, amd-ryzen

I've assembled my current computer several years ago, and it has two solid-state drives - an NVMe drive with a Linux installation and a SATA drive dedicated to Windows 10.

It is a first-generation Ryzen machine (1800x), with a B350M motherboard and an R9 390 GPU.

This setup has been running smoothly until a few months ago - Windows ran an automatic update after which Windows did not boot.

I tried recovering using a recovery USB, and finally decided to reinstall.

However, when installing, Windows takes a very long time (several hours) to install and gets stuck at the first boot. It always hangs around the same time and never recovers - even if I leave it overnight.

Just to clarify - this is the very same computer that previously ran Windows 10 just fine - I have not changed any part or peripheral.

I've tried lots of things to solve it:

- Installing on a different computer and relocating the SSD
- Disconnecting all non-essential hardware before installing (including other SSD)
- Running `dism` and `sfc` from the recovery environment
- Verifying the integrity of the drive, and the filesystem, from my Linux installation
- Installing an older version of Windows 10
- Cloning a working installation from a different computer
- Installing Windows 11 (my PC is unsupported, as it turns out).
- Changing UEFI settings to be more conservative (lower clocks, support all protocols, and a dedicated Windows 10 profile the motherboard came with)
- Running an extended S.M.A.R.T check on the disk and testing memory stability with MemTest86 overnight, both of which cleared.

Before I dismiss Windows completely, I'd be thankful if anyone could provide other things I can try to solve this.

Thank you!

UPDATE: Windows manages to install just fine when booting via MBR, but not through GPT. I am very confused...

Comment: Perhaps a hardware problem? To verify, check the SMART data of the disk and run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I did try both checking the disk and the memory - I just forgot to state it in the question :)

Comment: I suggest formatting the disk before installing Windows from scratch. If you don't have backups, do them first.

Comment: Pretty there it's a disk issue. SMART doesn't quickly update it's values when sectors are not bad but slow . Boot into RSAT or Windows PE to check the boot logs that stay on disk.
Otherwise try installing with one disk only for a test.
The best way to troubleshoot the disk - to run MHDD, Victoria or HDDScan to check the surface and real sectors state.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions! I zeroed out the disk and confirmed there are no bad sectors, but unfortunately the issue remains.

Comment: See if the issue repeats in some or the other way when you do a fresh install of Linux on the same SSD in GPT mode. If there's a firmware update (BIOS/UEFI) available for the motherboard, try to update BIOS to the latest version and check again.